# Nested loops array in Go not behaving like other languages' array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go

Why is this function printing out an array of `[83 83 83 83 83]` instead of `[98 93 77 82 83]` ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x [5]float64
    scores := [5]float64{ 98, 93, 77, 82, 83, }

    for i, _ := range x {
        for j, _ := range scores {
            // fill up x array with elements of scores array
            x[i] = scores[j]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are filling `x[i]` with each of the values of `scores`.
You have one extra loop.

Since the last value of the slice `scores` is 83, you are filling `x` one more time, with 83 for each slot.

Simpler would be:

```
for i, _ := range x {
    // fill up x array with elements of scores array
    x[i] = scores[i]
}
```

[<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/AbdPrIFnaQ)

Output: `[98 93 77 82 83]`

Comment: The play link appears to be hello world.

Comment: @ams I have fixed the play.golang.org link

Answer (score 1):

You have too many loops. Write:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x [5]float64
    scores := [5]float64{98, 93, 77, 82, 83}
    for i := range x {
        x[i] = scores[i]
    }
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
[98 93 77 82 83]
```

In this case, you could simply write:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x [5]float64
    scores := [5]float64{98, 93, 77, 82, 83}
    x = scores
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
[98 93 77 82 83]
```